# Move files from one folder to multiple subfolders in folders based on start of filename YYYY-MM

Tags: macos, applescript, automator

Wishing to optimize my photography workflow, I want to automate the moval of pictures and videos from (a) main folder into a set of folders' subfolders based on the start of the filename - all based on year and month, i.e. YYYY-MM. Ideally, it should run every time a new file appears in the/a defined main folder but if that's not simple to do, I would be okay to have a droplet/app that I should either run manually or otherwise schedule to run.

I'm not a programmer and I do not do scripting but I can understand most things when there's an apparent logic to the layman. I have read through numerous, similar posts but none provide an apparent answer that I can use and/or figure out how to adapt to what I'm trying to do with my files and folder hierarchies. From what I see, how people are either doing these things in Applescript or other script languages(?), for the right person, I think/hope this is a simple ask.

I have no good way of explaining what I'm trying to do other than visually, so here goes. Let me know if you have any questions. Thanks!

[image: move files to subfolders by YYYY-MM based filename and folder names]

Answer (score 0):

For this, I'd use an **Automator** *Folder Action* with **Run Shell Script** *action*, with settings as shown in the image further below, while replacing the default *code* in the **Run Shell Script** *action* with the following *example* **shell script** *code*:

```bash
p="$HOME/Photos"

for f in "$@"; do
    [ -f "${f}" ] || continue
    fn="${f##*/}"
    [[ ${fn} =~ ^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}.* ]] || continue
    y="${fn:0:4}"
    m="${fn:5:2}" 
    mkdir -p "${p}/${y}/${y}-${m}/${y}-${m} - To Sort" || exit
    mv -n "${f}" "${p}/${y}/${y}-${m}/${y}-${m} - To Sort"
done
```

To test the *example* **shell script** *code*, I created the **Photos** and **Photos to Sort** *folders* in my **Home** *folder* and assigned the later to the *Folder Action* in my **Automator** *workflow*.

Starting without any *subfolders* in the **Photos** *folder* or *files* in the **Photos to Sort** *folder*, I dragged and dropped the following *files* into the **Photos to Sort** *folder*:

- 2020-12-31 - file.jpg
- 2021-01-12 - file.mp4
- 2021-01-16 - file.jpg
- 2021-02-24 - file.jpg
- 2021-03-25 - file.mov

Upon doing do so, this triggered the **Automator** *Folder Action* moving the *files* to the appropriate *hierarchical folder structure* as shown below:

```
Photos % tree
.
├── 2020
│   └── 2020-12
│       └── 2020-12 - To Sort
│           └── 2020-12-31 - file.jpg
└── 2021
    ├── 2021-01
    │   └── 2021-01 - To Sort
    │       ├── 2021-01-12 - file.mp4
    │       └── 2021-01-16 - file.jpg
    ├── 2021-02
    │   └── 2021-02 - To Sort
    │       └── 2021-02-24 - file.jpg
    └── 2021-03
        └── 2021-03 - To Sort
            └── 2021-03-25 - file.mov

10 directories, 5 files
Photos %
```

---

[image: Automator Folder Action]

---

**Notes:**

In this particular use case IMO it's much easier to write *shell script code* than **AppleScript** *code*, and is why I went this route.

The `mv` *command* as coded will not overwrite an existing *file* because of the `-n` *option*. If you want existing *files* to be overwritten remove the `-n` *option* from the `mv` *command*.

The *shell script* checks what was dropped into the *folder* assigned to the *Folder Action* is a *file* or continues to the next **Finder** *item* dropped if more than one was dropped.

It checks that the *filename* is in the e.g. **YYYY-MM-DD ...** format or continues to the next **Finder** *item* dropped if more than one was dropped.

Creates the destination *hierarchical folder structures* as needed and then moves the target *files* to the appropriate destination *folders*.

The `tree` *command* used to show contents of the **Photos** *folder* is not a default **macOS** *command*.

Shell Script Variable Nomenclature:

- f = fully qualified pathname
- fn = filename with extension
- y = year
- m = month